# SQL-запрос в MySQL сквозь таблицу

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

Я имею следующие таблицы:
Издательский дом (PRINT_HOUSE)
Заказы (ORDERS)
Издания (EDITIONS)
Книги (BOOKS). Все таблицы связаны ключами .
Orders унаследовал ключ от print_house .
Orders унаследовал ключ от edition .
Edition унаследоуал от books. Могу ли я из издательского дома обратиться к заказу, от заказа к изданию а от издания к книгам чтобы узнать какие книги я печатаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете,  запрос будет вроде такого:

```
SELECT `B`.*
FROM `books` AS `B`
LEFT JOIN `edition` AS `E` ON `E`.`id` = `B`.`edition_id`
LEFT JOIN `orders` AS `O` ON `O`.`id` = `E`.`order_id`
LEFT JOIN `print_house` AS `PH` ON `PH`.`id` = `O`.`print_house_id`
WHERE /* условие на print_house */
```

Если нам надо получить книги по `print_house.id`, то можно таблицу `print_house` не джоинить:

```
SELECT `B`.*
FROM `books` AS `B`
LEFT JOIN `edition` AS `E` ON `E`.`id` = `B`.`edition_id`
LEFT JOIN `orders` AS `O` ON `O`.`id` = `E`.`order_id`
WHERE `O`.`print_house_id` = 'нужный_id'
```